# Closure compiler doesn't virtualize prototype functions contained inside anonymous wrapper

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm experimenting with advanced mode of Google Closure Compiler and it seems like small simple functions are inlined only when not wrapped in an anonymous wrapper. Looking for an explanation/solution or hint of what I'm doing wrong.

This is my test:

```
function Test() {
}
Test.prototype.div = function (index) {
    return Math.floor(index / 32);
};
Test.prototype['test'] = function (index) {
    return this.div(index);
};
window['Test'] = Test;
```

which results in this small script where the `div` function is **inlined**:

```
function a() { } 
a.prototype.test = function(b) { return Math.floor(b / 32) }; 
window.Test = a;
```

Next, the test is wrapped like:

```
(function () { // <-- added
    function Test() {
    }

    Test.prototype.div = function (index) {
        return Math.floor(index / 32);
    };

    Test.prototype['test'] = function (index) {
        return this.div(index);
    };

    window['Test'] = Test;
}()); // <-- added
```

The `div` function is **not inlined**:

```
(function() { 
    function a() { } 
    a.prototype.a = function(a) { return Math.floor(a / 32) }; 
    a.prototype.test = function(a) { return this.a(a) }; 
    window.Test = a
})();
```

Is there some side-effect that I'm not aware of that is preventing inlining here?

**Update 1**: I'm using [online compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) with advanced-mode + pretty-print ticked.

**Update 2**: Found out that the command line parameter `--output_wrapper` can be used as a workaround, `--output_wrapper "(function() {%output%})();"`.

Comment: This is not inlining, but prototype virtualization.  It is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=458&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Thanks for correcting the terminology; interesting read in the issue report as well (almost exact the same example as I came up with). If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it

Comment: FYI, you are talking about inlining. Stephen is talking about "devirtualization" which is one way the compiler enables inlining and other optimizations.  The compiler is capable of inlining methods in ADVANCED mode without devirtualizing first but the code in question is very conservative.

Comment: @John, I think inlining within a closure is supported in newer versions of the compiler, but not if it is a prototype, which must be virtualized first into a global function before being inlined, because inlining does not occur for prototype functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not inlining, but prototype virtualization

It is a known issue: [Closure compiler issue](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=458&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Owner%20Summary)

Comment: As I just learned; _visualization_ should be _virtualization_ :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, nothing preventing inlining except logic to do it in the compiler.